# Javascript - Como criar arrays bidimensionais e percorrê-los com laços de repetição?

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo, caso eu queira um criar um algoritmo com 3 linhas e 4 colunas, em que cada linha é um aluno, e cada coluna são as notas desse aluno (1º bimestre,2ºbimestre,3ºbimestre,4ºbimestre), como poderia ser feito em Javascript? em linguagens como JAVA ou C eu já fiz, porém em Javascript não funciona, um exemplo de como eu tentei em javascript, mas não funcionou:

```
var notas = [][];

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    notas[i] = prompt('NOME DO ALUNO: ');
    for (let y = 1; y < 5; y++) {
        notas[i][y] = Number(prompt(`${y}ºBIMESTRE: `));
    }
}
```

Comment: E o nome do aluno fica em qual posição? 5ª?

Comment: Eu visualizo isso como uma matriz bidimensional, imagine uma tabela do excel, os nomes ficariam nas linhas, e as notas nas colunas, a minha idéia é essa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um array de objetos, onde cada objeto guarda o nome do aluno + as 4 notas, neste formato (os valores são hipotéticos):

```
notas = [
   {nome: "aluno1", nota1: 2, nota2: 4, nota3: 5, nota4: 9}
   ...
]
```

Funciona assim:

```
var notas = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   let aluno = prompt('NOME DO ALUNO: ');
    notas.push({nome: aluno});
    for (let y = 1; y < 5; y++) {
        notas[i-1]["nota"+y] = Number(prompt(`${y}ºBIMESTRE: `));
    }
}
```

**Para percorrer neste formato (array de objetos):**

```js
var notas = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   let aluno = prompt('NOME DO ALUNO: ');
    notas.push({nome: aluno});
    for (let y = 1; y < 5; y++) {
        notas[i-1]["nota"+y] = Number(prompt(`${y}ºBIMESTRE: `));
    }
}

// percorrer

notas.forEach(function(e){
   
   let texto = `<strong>Aluno:</strong> ${e.nome}<br>
   Nota 1: ${e["nota"+1]}<br>
   Nota 2: ${e["nota"+2]}<br>
   Nota 3: ${e["nota"+3]}<br>
   Nota 4: ${e["nota"+4]}<br>
   `;
   
   document.write(texto);
   
});
```

---

Ou se quiser criar arrays dento de arrays, neste formato:

```
notas = [
   ["aluno1", 1, 2, 3, 4]
   ...
]
```

Onde o índice `[0]` das subarrays é o nome do aluno e os índices subsequentes são as notas:

```
var notas = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   let aluno = [prompt('NOME DO ALUNO: ')];
    notas.push(aluno);
    for (let y = 1; y < 5; y++) {
        notas[i-1].push(Number(prompt(`${y}ºBIMESTRE: `)));
    }
}
```

**Para percorrer neste formato (array de arrays):**

```js
var notas = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   let aluno = [prompt('NOME DO ALUNO: ')];
    notas.push(aluno);
    for (let y = 1; y < 5; y++) {
        notas[i-1].push(Number(prompt(`${y}ºBIMESTRE: `)));
    }
}

// percorrer

notas.forEach(function(e){
   
   let texto = `<strong>Aluno:</strong> ${e[0]}<br>
   Nota 1: ${e[1]}<br>
   Nota 2: ${e[2]}<br>
   Nota 3: ${e[3]}<br>
   Nota 4: ${e[4]}<br>
   `;
   
   document.write(texto);
   
});
```